# Where is the html for "Server Error in '/' Application" stored, and can it be edited?

Tags: .net, error-handling

Can I edit the template for the .net default error page?

The big red title `Server Error in '/'` is often all a user will inform a developer about, and the slash is always confusing for them.

Whilst the default error handling in .net shouldn't be used in a production environment, there are still times when it is helpful to have it showing during test phases, or on an intranet. I am aware that code should contain error handling, but these default error pages were created for a reason so I believe my question is nevertheless valid.

In older IIS / Classic ASP days the files were stored in `C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US` but these are not the ones .net uses, so is there a different folder I can look at? I've hunted through the server's system drive to no avail.

Surely the CSS for this page isn't hardcoded in a DLL somewhere?! I was expecting a template that could be at least styled, even if it couldn't have the text changed.

Comment: Wonder if you could use the IIS settings that point to the custom error files to do this.